# What is the French phrase for "window shopping"?

Tags: expressions

What is the French phrase for "window shopping"?

Would be glad to know its origin, if possible, the word etymology. Where is it derived from?

Comment: That is no question for the FSE; the answer is in any English-French dictionary. for example; https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/window%20shopping/forced

Comment: If that's what you want, you should first find the translation and then phrasse your question according to your wish; check the column thouroughly, it's at the bottom; moreover I do find the term also in a Harrap dictionary (paper).

Comment: No problem, Good Luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common equivalent idiom is *faire du lèche-vitrines* (literally, "licking the windows of the shops").

Comment: M'étant permis de dégager le tag *ancien-français* de la question, je précise juste : Les ngrams le datent de 1946, sa première apparition dans un dictionnaire de 1959, le premier roman dans lequel je le trouve de 1970.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!